# Change in 'default store' setting in Magento makes admin panel inaccessable?

Tags: .htaccess, url, magento, url-rewriting, e-commerce

We have a multi-store Magento installation with stores in several countries. Today, we changed the default store setting from one store to another. After saving this setting, the admin URL for the installation (http://store.OURWEBSITE.com/admin) no longer worked.

I suspect that this is an `.htaccess` problem. Does anyone know the direct link, i.e., http://store.OURWEBSITE.com/p=admin, that will let us access the admin to change this back?

Thanks!

Comment: What does "no longer worked" mean?

Comment: when attempting to access the admin URL, I am redirected to the store home page—it feels like an .htaccess error. I know that's simplistic, but it's about the extent of the problem. I'm not privy to how the Magento system handles url-rewrites, but that seems to be what's happening. Thanks!

Comment: Are you actually HTTP redirected, or does going to the "admin" page render the home page?

Comment: Going to the admin page 'renders' the home page—the URL stays the same (/admin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into similar issues before. The way I got it fixed is to make sure that the Base URL and Secure Base URL of the "default configuration" are set to the same value as the Base URL and Secure Base URL of the website that is set as default.

If you can't access your admin anymore you can go into your database and edit the values directly in the table `core_config_data`. You need to look for the path `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url`. The "default configuration" has `scope_id` zero.

Comment: And in case caching is still on be sure to empty the directory `var/cache/` after making database changes.